# Similarity of linear transformation and Eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have two diagonalizeable linear transformations $L:W \rightarrow W$ and $K:W \rightarrow W$ and lemma says that they are same if and only if they have same eigen values and same eigenvectors.

For one side it is true:

$L$ and $K$ are same    $\leftarrow$ $L$ and $K$ have same eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

I came to this result by constructing a diagonal matrix  $D$ where eigenvalues are the diagonal elements of the matrix and remaining elements are zeros and because $L $~$ D$ and $K$~$D$ $\rightarrow $ $L $~$ K$

Now i want to go other side(i don't know if it is true or not) but i could not find any counter example so i'm lookig for a relation.

What i understood that if two transformations are similar(which i know) then characterisc polynomial is independent of chosen basis. So eigenvalues and eigenvectors should also be same but i can't prove it! I mean in mathematical notation. Can some tell me where to start?

Thanks

Comment: The characteristic polynomial only gives you eigenvalues. Eigenvectors are dependent on the specific matrix.

Comment: If L and K are the same then the may differ only up to a change of basis, thus they are similar. Thus they share eigenvalues but in general not the eigenvectors, which depends upon the basis.

Comment: @gimusi i understand what you say and this mean above lemma is only valid in one direction? if i'm not wrong.